# how the JIT interpretator compiles heavy computing parts of code in android

Tags: android, jit, dalvik

I am new to Android and i was reading about Dalvik VM .In Android platform all applications are in .dex format. Now when we launch a application having a heavy computation code then JIT interpretator will take one instruction , compile it and execution of that instruction will be done , but if it encounters a heavy computation code ,it will that complete part of code and compile it in native language and save the compiled code for future reference , so that next time it will directly use the compiled code .
**Now my question is that will that compile code will remain forever or it will remain upto when the application is running and when application is re-launched in future , it will again compile that part of code.**

Comment: More or less on topic: Android now introduced a beta-stage (but working well) new runtime, called Android Runtime (ART). It compiles dex code ahead of time and stores it for as long as the application is installed. [More information](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/the-art-of-android/).

Comment: ya i know it that now they have moved to ART , but still i want to know answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

The JIT-compiled code is not preserved.  When the process is killed, the JIT code cache is freed.  The compilation is done anew when the app is restarted.

Note this is *process* death.  Nothing goes away if the app simply moves into the background because you've switched to another app.

Comment: but i have seen in one of my mobile phone that , he has used 5-6 application and after he has closed those application he showed me the cache content using a application in android phone ...yes i remember it...and thts why i asked this question here because earlier i used to think that when the application are gone , all data related to that application in RAM is also freed .

Comment: I can't really speak to what you were shown since I wasn't there.  All apps have a data cache that can be cleared from app settings, but that cache does not include JIT-compiled code.  For example, the Calendar will store recently downloaded information about upcoming events.  That way, even if you reboot your phone while out of range of a network, you will still receive notifications.

Comment: ok , if i get some other thing then i will comment here , right now m favoring you...